# Reverse Voltage Protection using PMOS: Bias Resistor selection

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, circuit-protection, pmos

[image]

1.How to calculate the bias resistor value (100R in snip attached) ?.
2.Is the resistor value depend on Zener clamping value?

Comment: The zener has a minimum current to properly regulate (and a max current to not fry, obviously).

Comment: I think the easiest way is to decide how much current you want in the resistor. Probably 100 uA or more. Then solve for R. The Zener voltage depends on the current a little bit. For example, maybe it will be 13 V with 5 mA and 11 V with 100 uA (made up numbers). Just use the nominal voltage for your calculation. After you build the circuit you can change the resistor value a little bit to get more or less current.

Comment: Why the Zener (i am tired) ? Any resistor (or none) should do without the Zener

Comment: @tobalt good question. OP should answer. But maybe the OP needs to use this circuit in a case where the voltage is higher than Vgs(max) of the mosfet.

Comment: @tobalt Limited Vgs_max relative to the expected operating voltages.

Comment: Ahh of course  I knew it looked too simple with only the FET..

Comment: @tobalt Go to bed

Comment: @mkeith Could you tell how to do that calculation. Considering Vbat = 16V and ZD1 clamping voltage 15V. i.e (16-15)/100R = 10mA , is that correct?